# Show Fixed Number of Cells in a UITableView:-Scrolling issue iOS

Tags: ios

I am getting the number of cells from the server and only want to show 5 cells of the table view at a time.

I have a 'more' and 'previous' button that should load the next five or previous five cells. For example if cell 10-15 are visible pressing more should show cells 16-20.

Now if I have 62 rows to be displayed, the last iteration should only show 2 cells i.e 61 and 62 and nothing else.

I am able to scroll to a particular cell using:
 `(void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated`

However that doesn't show the next chunk of cells from the top.
For example at position 5 if I press 'more', the cell number 6 gets displayed at the bottom and topmost gets hidden. Instead I want it to show cell 6-10 and so on.

What is the correct way to implement such a way of scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

there is UITableView Properties called **[tableView beginUpdates],[tableView endUpdates],** so u can go through them. it will solve ur problem